# generate menu from object dynamically angularjs

Tags: angularjs, object, menu

im trying to generate a dynamic menu items from an object, the main gola is to get a custom menu for user roles, to do this i want to pass a object to the directive but i can't figured out

heres is my directive code:

```
.directive("menu", function() {
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  scope: { model: "=" },
  templateUrl: "app/views/menu.html",
  link: function($scope, element, attr) {
    $scope.parentId = attr.id;
  },
  controller: function($scope, $timeout, $http) {

  var menu = {}

  $scope.menu = menu
 }
});
```

regards

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
scope: {
  model: '='
}
```

you are telling Angular to create a binding to the object in the "model" attribute on that element. Like so:

```
<menu model="object"></menu>
```

You can then access that object using scope.model in your link function (it's just scope, not $scope, in your link function)